# How can I deploy a .Net application in the subfolder of a website?

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis-7

I have a .Net 4.0 project called *BasicTestProject* and it contains a webform called *Default*.

**Default.aspx:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" 
         CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BasicTestProject.Default" %>
```

**Default.aspx.cs:**

```
namespace BasicTestProject 
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

I want to put a compiled version of this application in the subfolder of a website:

- Website Root

  - SubFolder

    - **BasicTestProject**

At the Website Root I have a basic web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.web>
        <compilation targetFramework="4.0" />
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

I made a test of the example above and when I try to access the site within a Subfolder (*http://WebsiteRoot/SubFolder/BasicTestProject/Default.aspx*), this is the error I am getting:

```
Parser Error 

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately. 

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'BasicTestProject.Default'.

Source Error: 

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BasicTestProject.Default" %>
Line 2:  
Line 3:  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

Source File: /*WebsiteRoot*/*SubFolder*/BasicTestProject/default.aspx    Line: 1 

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.272
```

Also, I should mention that I have tried placing my compiled BasicTestProject on its own IP address so that it sits at the root folder. That works as expected and I can access Default.aspx.

**UPDATE (answer):**

In IIS7 I right-clicked BasicTestProject and converted it in to an application.

- Website Root

  - SubFolder

    - **BasicTestProject**

I had to also grant the Application Pool user permission to the BasicTestProject folder. It is now self-contained and running.

Comment: Does the BasicTestProject bin folder need to sit at the Website Root?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll elaborate on @MikeC's answer a bit: In IIS there is the concept of "application scope" which is a sub-hierarchy of the *filesystem* tree which belongs to the same conceptual "application".

The root of every individual IIS website is also marked as the root of a new application scope. Any server-side code that is executed in a scope runs in the Application Pool that the scope belongs to (CGI and FastCGI processes are launched under the identity of the scope's pool, for example). ASP.NET takes this further by defining the root of an application scope to be where it expects to find the `bin` directory as well as allowing more `web.config` options to be defined.

As I said, this applies to the filesystem hierarchy, so if you're using URL Rewriting or ASP.NET URL Routing then it complicates things.

(This was originally a comment reply to Mike's answer, but it overran the message length).

Comment: Thanks, and no I'm not using url routing. I will give it a shot (converting BasicTestProject folder in to an application).

Comment: So in IIS I am right-clicking the BasicTestProject folder and choosing 'Covert to Application'. In cmd I am using icacls to set permission to the application to the application pool "user"..  will keep you posted

Comment: It shouldn't be necessary to change any NTFS permissions unless your application pool user identity didn't already have Read access. You only need to grant Write permission to a directory where you'll be saving uploaded files, for example.

Comment: Also, please confirm that you have a file called "BasicTestProject.dll" located within a folder called `bin` in your website's root.

Comment: Thanks that explanation of permissions really helps. I got it working, and i do not have the dll in website root/bin. That is what I set out to accomplish though, because I want to keep the root website as clean as possible (no bin folder if possible)

Answer (score 2):

Did you configure that subfolder as an application in IIS?